# How to terminate an Ansible playbook run when it is successful on one host?

Tags: ansible

I have a system with several hosts for availability. I only need to run my Ansible playbook on one host. However some of these hosts may not be reachable. Let's say I have host1, host2, host3 ... If host1 is not reachable, I want Ansible to try host2. If host2 is reachable and Ansible runs some bash scripts successfully, I want Ansible to skip the rest of hosts. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you define "some" in "*runs some bash scripts successfully*"?

Comment: And how do you define "unreachable"? Ansible automatically skips hosts unreachable by ssh.

Comment: @sm4rk0 I'm curious how would it influence the answer? The only determinant whether to continue trying or to stop is a successful execution (of mysterious "some" scripts). What role does the definition of "unreachable" play for the answer, in your opinion?

Comment: @techraf You're right. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the optimal solution, but I couldn't find a better one.

- (Optionally) Set [`gather_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#turning-off-facts) to `False`, to entirely skip the hosts that need to be skipped (if you don't need to gather the host facts).
- Set [`serial`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) to 1, so the playbook is played entirely on one host at a time instead of the default 5 hosts in parallel.
- Use [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) to set a host fact (named `done` in example) to `True` at the end of a play, or use [`register`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#sts=Registered%20Variables) if you need a more specific condition (a command output).
- Use [`end_play` `meta`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/meta_module.html) at the start of the play that would execute when the variable is set to `True` (or has the expected value, if you used `register`) for any host. I used the [Jinja2 template language](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) to extract the value this way:

  1. `for` to loop over all the `hostvars` (Python dict containing all the variables set for all hosts in the inventory).
  2. `if` to check whether a host has `done` variable set to `True` and return a string `True` if it is.
  3. `default` filter to set the default value if `done` is not defined for a host (that would cause an error `'dict object' has no attribute 'done'`).

For example:

```
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - meta: end_play
    when: "{% for item in hostvars.values() %}{% if item.done|default(False) %}True{% endif %}{% endfor %}"

  # The rest of the play goes here

  - set_fact:
      done: True
```

Answer (score -1):

Ansible doesn't consider those hosts which are not reachable, in setup phase unreachable hosts list will be dropped.

On remaining list of hosts use 'run_once: yes' for that specific task of that bash script. It will pick first matching host from available hosts.